# SQL Query - adding output to SELECT statement

Tags: sqlite

I have written an SQL query which amalgamates data from two separate tables with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table 2
ORDER BY column 1
```

What I'd like to be able to do is to add a column or 'stamp' in a newly created column which details the table which each text entry originally came from. So my output would have a column which detailed the table which each row was originally from.
Essentially, the tables I have are made up of large quantities of numeric data and are hard to distinguish upon completing the Union command.

Thanks for any help.
Regards,
CJW.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a scalar value from your selects, but you need to specify columns instead of `*`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 'TABLE1' FROM table 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT col1, col2, 'TABLE2' FROM table 2 ORDER BY column 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this Mike. Works very well - only (small) issue is that some of these tables have 20ish columns and it's a bit of a pain to list every column!

Comment: Well, if it's something you use often just create a view out of it and you only have to write it one time.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add any expression(s) anywhere in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS SourceTable FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 AS SourceTable FROM Table2
ORDER BY Column1;
```